# Can't we use other than fetch method we set as default in ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE?

Tags: php, php-7

I Set `PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,` as default in connection and now I am having problem with fetchAll problem.

The problem I am having is :

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\wamp\www\a\test.php on line 59
```

And line 59 is :

```
if($sql->fetchAll()[0][0] !== '0' && $level !== 0){
```

Here is my connection type:

```
$host = 'localhost';
$db   = 'demo';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$options = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => TRUE,
);
try {
     $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
     throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}
```

And Here is the query I am trying :
if I remove `ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE` it works fine, is there a way to use both ?

```
function bootstrap_menu($pdo, $parent_id, $level = null) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id =:parent_id");
    $stmt->bindParam(":parent_id", $parent_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    foreach ($stmt->fetchAll() as $row) {
        $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM categories WHERE parent_id =:cat_id");
        $sql->bindParam(":cat_id", $row['cat_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sql->execute();
        if($sql->fetchColumn()[0][0] !== '0' && $level !== 0){  
            echo "<li class=\"nav-item dropdown\">\n";
            echo "<a class=\"nav-link dropdown-toggle\" href=\"".htmlspecialchars($row['seo_url'])."\" id=\"navbarDropdown\" role=\"button\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\"
                    aria-haspopup=\"true\" aria-expanded=\"false\">\n";
            echo $row['cat_name'];
            echo "</a>\n";
            echo "<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\" aria-labelledby=\"navbarDropdown\">\n";
            bootstrap_menu($pdo, $row[0], $level - 1);
            echo "</ul>\n";
            echo "</li>\n";
        }elseif($level == 0){
            $my_class = htmlspecialchars($row['cat_name']);         
            if($my_class == 'Ana Sayfa'){
                echo "<li class=\"nav-item active\">\n";
                echo "<a href=\"".htmlspecialchars($row['seo_url'])."\" class=\"nav-link \">\n";
                echo htmlspecialchars($row['cat_name']);
                echo "</a>\n";
                echo "</li>\n";
            }else{
                echo "<li class=\"nav-item\">\n";
                echo "<a href=\"".htmlspecialchars($row['seo_url'])."\" class=\"nav-link\">\n";
                echo htmlspecialchars($row['cat_name']);
                echo "</a>\n";
                echo "</li>\n";
            }
        }
        else { 
            echo "<li class=\"dropdown-item\">";
            echo "<a href=\"".htmlspecialchars($row['seo_url'])."\" class=\"dropdown-item\">\n";
            echo htmlspecialchars($row['cat_name']);
            echo "</a>\n";
            echo "</li>\n";
        }
        unset($sql);
    }
    unset($stmt);
}
```

Comment: Did you consider the possibility to use a different fetch method, other than fetchAll()?

Comment: Besides, instead of two queries it should be a single query with a GROUP BY clause

Comment: You are not making any attempt to override the default fetch mode set in the constructor, that explains why it isn't happening (see [Dharman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58671171/13508)) for that. You're also assuming that the secondary query can never return zero rows (i.e., that all first level categories necessarily have second level subcategories, if I understood correctly).

Comment: sorry I was away I tried `if($sql->fetchColumn()[0][0] !== '0' && $level !== 0){` is well then it gives another error **Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in line 66** `bootstrap_menu($pdo, $row[0], $level - 1);`

Comment: As I said in my answer `$sql->fetchColumn()[0][0]` is wrong. You changed the code in the question and now I do not know where you are seeing what error.

Comment: No I didnt change the code, its the same code but I added full code in question, and the problem is the same, as I answered your question about `$row[0]` too in your coment for your answer. your answer is right for general usage pdo fetchColumn, but not an answer for my question, this is the original post same as mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40365952/dynamic-menu-php-bootstrap-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$sql->fetchAll()[0][0]` means simply first column of the first row. There already is a method for that in PDO [`fetchColumn()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php).

You just need:

```
if($sql->fetchColumn() !== '0' && $level !== 0)
```

or even better

```
if($sql->fetchColumn() && $level !== 0)
```

If for whatever reason you still want to use `fetchAll()` then you can pass the fetch style as an argument. e.g. `$sql->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_BOTH)`

Also in the outer loop `foreach ($stmt->fetchAll() as $row)` is not really needed. Simply `foreach ($stmt as $row)`

Comment: Sorry I was away fetchAll part is not in foreach its in an if statement I tried `if($sql->fetchColumn()[0][0] !== '0' && $level !== 0){` is well then it gives another error **Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in line 66** `bootstrap_menu($pdo, $row[0], $level - 1);`

Comment: You don't need `[0][0]`. Just `if($sql->fetchColumn() !== '0'` or even better `if($sql->fetchColumn() && $level !== 0`

Comment: tought that is checking for parent id ? let me try that way

Comment: I tried both solutions in your comment and having error with both solutions for child cats : Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in line 66. Which is `bootstrap_menu($pdo, $row[0], $level - 1);`

Comment: What is `$row[0]`?

Comment: The item is a parent, in case we call the Menu function with the item id `$row[0]` as a parent and `$level - 1` to make sure to stop when reach the end of levels.  – Dharman